# Recursive function not getting called in nested loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, recursion, nested-loops

I am trying to do a graph traversal. Since all vertices are not connected. I need to initiate the traversal from every node. Nodes are in a 2d array. I am getting the input from a large text file and here is how I do it:

```
lr.on('end', function(){
 //Callback called when file reading is complete
 initialize(); //initialize stuff
 startTraversal();
});
```

The `startTraversal()` method is defined as:

```
 function startTraversal(){
   for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    for(j=0;j<y;j++){
        console.log(i+', '+j);
        traverse(i,j); //Call Traverse i,j every time once
    }
   }
 }
```

`traverse(i,j)` is a recursive function. So I look at all possible paths from the node `i,j` and initiate `traverse` on them. A broad structure of the `traverse()` method is below:

```
function traverse(i,j){
var possible = getAdjacent(i,j); //getPossible Routes
if(possible.length == 0){
    //do stuff
    return; //Tried adding return statement here
}

else{
    for(x=0;x<possible.length;x++){
        if(!data[a][b].visited) //if node is not visited
            traverse(a,b);

        //Do further stuff when this ^ call returns, finding max etc
        ...
       } //End of for
    }
}
```

Now in the `startTraversal()` function call, the inner loop is executed only for the first value of `i` which I confirmed from the `console.log`. I am not able to understand why is the loop not getting executed further.

**PS:** When I manually put the nested loops outside any callbacks, the loops and traversal gets done as expected. However, I need to initiate the `startTraversal()` method only when the file is read completely. I guess it has something to do with the `traverse()` function not returning a value so that the loop is not continued. I tried adding a `return` in the base case of `traverse` method but to no success.

Any insights on this problem is deeply appreciated. Would want to know how to handle recursive calls in nested loops, atleast in javascript.

Comment: You really must declare the variables in the functions ... Currently all loops share the same counters.

Comment: Please, getAdjacent() method, does it has a callback? And when you said that the inner loop is executed only for the first value of i, you means the value 0? In real I want to know if code you didn't write contains callbacks methods

Comment: I don't see how all the loops use the same counter. I am passing variables `i` and `j` as paramters to the `traverse` function. They will be passed by value right.

Comment: @Ediruth, `getAdjacent()` method doesn't have a callback. It just returns an `array`.

Comment: `x` in `for(x=0;x<possible.length;x++)` is shared with all recursive function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never, ever (*) use global variables. It seems that your `x, y, i, j` (and possibly other) variables are global, which is probably the cause of your problems.

`x & y` look like some kind of "dimensionality" vars of your array/graph/whatever, so it's better to pass them as arguments of `startTraversal`. `i & j` are local variables, so they should be declared inside the function they are used in (eg. `for(var i = 0; i < x; i++)`). It also might be a good idea to pass the graph itself as an argument of all your graph-related functions.

You should also consider using [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). One of the restriction is you are not allowed to accidentally create global vars.

---

(*) - of course there are some cases where global variables are actually desired, but it mostly concerns people creating some kind of global, reusable modules or constant, shared values. You should never use globals for your "local" operations.

Comment: Thanks @mdziekon for pointing out about Strict mode. Indeed I was reusing `x` in the function which was causing the error.